# Need help solving a convolution problem involving Bessel function

Tags: convolution, bessel-functions

so I've been asked to solve $$\int_{0}^\infty J_0(u)J_0(t-u)du$$ I know that $$L[J_0(u)] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{s^2+a^2}}$$ and from that I can guess it has to do something with substituting $u=at$ and seems to me that the answer would be along the lines of $$f * g = L^{-1}[F(s)G(s)]$$but I'm just not quite sure how to land the idea, would really appreciate the help.

Comment: The anti-Laplace transform of a lorentzian is $\theta(t)\sin(at)$. This should help.

Comment: So with that idea, and if I'm right about $F(s)=G(s)$ then the answer would be: $L^{-1}[\frac{1}{s^2+a^2}]=\frac{1}{a}sin(at)$ is that correct?